# Pointer array of pointers with C?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I want an array of pointers and I want to set byte values in the memory addresses where the pointers (of the array) are pointing.

Would this work:

```
unsigned int *pointer[4] = {(unsigned int *) 0xFF200020, (unsigned int *) 0xFF20001C, (unsigned int *) 0xFF200018, (unsigned int *) 0xFF200014};
*pointer[0] = 0b0111111; // the value is correct for the address
```

Or is the syntax somehow different?

EDIT:
I'm coding for an SOC board and these are memory addresses that contain the case of some UI elements.

```
unsigned int *element1 = (unsigned int *) 0xFF200020;
*element1 = 0b0111111;
```

works so I'm just interested about the C syntax of this.

EDIT2: There was one 0 too much in ... = 0b0...

Comment: Are those addresses for hardware registers? If they are, you might want to declare them `volatile` to prevent compiler from making invalid optimizations.

Comment: Yes they are. Maybe I add volatile to those but so far the I havent't have any problems with `unsigned int *element1 = (unsigned int *) 0xFF200020;
*element1 = 0b00111111;` kind of typing

Comment: Syntax doesn't seem wrong (aside from non-standard `0b00111111`). Are you having some other problem with this code?

Comment: I just got this idea and I don't have the hardware here with me right now. So I just wanted to make sure this would work :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Short answer:

Everything you've written is fine.

#### Thoughts:

- I'm a big fan of using the types from `stdint.h`. This would let you write `uint32_t` which is more clearly a 32 bit unsigned number than `unsigned long`.
- You'll often see people write macros to refer to these registers:

  ```
  #define REG_IRQ (*(volatile uint32_t *)(0xFF200020))
  REG_IRQ = 0x42;
  ```
- It's possible that you actually want these pointers to be to `volatile` integers. You want it to be volatile if the value can change outside of the execution of your program. That is, if that memory position doesn't act strictly like a piece of memory. (For example, it's a register that stores the interrupt flags).

  With most compilers I've used on embedded platforms, you'll have problems from ignoring `volatile` once optimizations have been enabled.
- `0b00111111` is, sadly, non-standard. You can use octal, decimal, or hexadecimal.

Comment: This is the first time I'm coding for hardware, so I'm not sure about this.
Memory slots in the hardware I'm using are 32 bits. So would   `0b01111111` (octa?) or `0b00000000000000000000000001111111` (decimal) be standard?

Comment: @Masza He's referring to the `0b` part. Use 1234 (decimal), 0**x**1234 (hexa), or **0**1234 (octal) (Note that they represent different values, it's just a visual example.)

Answer (score 1):

Sure, this should work, providing you can find addresses in your own segment.

Most probably, you'll have a segmentation fault when running this code, because `0xFF200020` have really few chances to be in your program segment.

Answer (score 1):

This will not throw any error and will work fine but hard-coding memory address the pointer is pointing to is not a good idea. De-referencing some unknown/non-existing memory location will cause segmentation fault but if you are sure about the memory location and hard-coding values to them as done here is totally fine.

Comment: Yes I am sure about the memory location and this is the only way the thing I'm doing can be done.

Comment: @Masza Then just make sure you make other changes as suggested by others to use `volatile` and also remove the non-standard `0b001111111` and use some standard hex octal or decimal values